# How to remove MenuItem from DefaultMenuModel of Primefaces Breadcrumb

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

Hi I am building DefaultMenuModel programmatically which is being used by the  component as follows

```
`<p:breadCrumb id="pbreadcrumb" model="#{portalNavigator.model}"/>`
```

and  this is the code from PortalNavigator Bean which adds MenuItem to object model which is of type DefaultMenuModel.

```
DefaultMenuModel model=new DefaultMenuModel();    
MenuItem item=new MenuItem();  
item.setId("home");  
item.setUrl("/getPortal");  
item.setValue("Home");  
model.addMenuItem(item);
```

My question is How can I remove a MenuItem from DefaultMenuModel,what is the way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get them all by [`DefaultMenuModel#getContents()`](http://www.primefaces.org/docs/api/3.4/org/primefaces/model/DefaultMenuModel.html#getContents%28%29) which returns a `List<UIComponent>` whose items you can cast back to `MenuItem`. Loop over them in an `Iterator`. Once you found the item you want to remove, use `Iterator#remove()` method.

```
Iterator<UIComponent> iterator = model.getContents().iterator();

while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    MenuItem item = (MenuItem) iterator.next();

    if (needsRemoval(item)) {
        iterator.remove();
    }
}
```

Or, if you already know the index beforehand, you can also just do:

```
model.getContents().remove(index);
```